# How to configure the IPv6 address on Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, ip, ipv6, system-preferences

I have automatically configured IPv6 address on my Mac OS X 10.6:

```
$ ifconfig
...
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 00:16:cb:94:1a:79 
inet6 fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
inet 192.168.163.200 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 192.168.163.255
media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
status: active
...
```

and

```
$ sysctl -a
...
net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr: 1
...
```

(I don't know is it necessary)

But after I reconfigure the IPv6 address on Preference Pane (Networking) nothing changed.
How could I change my IPv6 address?

**Update**

I have select FEE2:f68::1986:69af address. The reason I do this to prevent adding the `%en0` to the address string.

Comment: You will always have a link local address according to the RFCs, but if you specify an address in Preferences, it should show up.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IPv6 you always have a link-local address (those that usually start with fe80:, although all addresses in the range `fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` - `febf:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` are link-local). The address you configure in the Preferences pane should show up on the interface. Configure a global IPv6 address on the interface, or if you don't have a global prefix then use [ULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address). The prefix length for a LAN is always /64, unless you really know what you are doing :-)

Comment: Oh, and the net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr: 1 is for when you don't manually configure your IPv6 address. Then it randomly generates its own address based on the information in the Router Advertisement (assuming you have a router on your network)

Comment: Just to say that the correct prefix of a link-local address is `fe80::/64` as specified in [RFC4291](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.6).

Comment: No it is not. The official prefix for link-local is fe80::/10, but yes: RFC4291 describes how the bits should be used. At the start of section 2.4 it specifies fe80::/10 though, and not a /64.